# Sending email in Azure IoT edge using function

Tags: azure-iot-edge

For the IoT edge function, input trigger is edgeHubTrigger and the output is edgeHub. How can we send email in IoT edge using function? And will this be suggested approach to do in IoT edge or we need to send to IoT Hub and the listener function (in the cloud) listens to IoT hub send email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Edge device, and your Edge function, have access to a mail server (or a service like SendGrid), then sure, you should be able to send emails. You should be able to use any .NET SMTP client library (or again, something like Sendgrid with their SDK).

If I would consider it a great design to send mails from the Edge device? This depends a bit on your scenario I would say: If you want to use some on-premise mail server, which is reachable from your Edge device but not from the cloud, then this might be a valid approach.

But if you use a mail server that you reach over the internet or some cloud mail service, then I would probably rather send those messages from the Edge to the IoT Hub in Azure (and put a property on them for routing), route them to an Azure Function and send them from there. This way you avoid putting your send logic onto each and every Edge device. Plus you automatically benefit from the message caching of the Edge Hub in case your Edge device is offline for a while.